# How can I know if a <router-link> link has been clicked using pure javascript, in VUEJS 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flowbite

I need to implement a Dropdown menu component which is made in  Flowbite, and utilized inside a VUEJS project. The Issue with this dropdown is that it doesnt hide when someone clicks a link inside it. So I need to implement the behavior. Can I have help please with a first step and tell me how to know, using just pure javascript, when a router link link has been clicked?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to replace `<router-link>` with normal text and add an onClick method where you can first toggle the dropdown menu visibility and then programmatically activate the navigation.

Comment: @yoduh, actually, if I replace the <router-link> for an <a> tag I wouldnt do any code because the <a> tag refreshes the page, so It will close the dropdown menu, but what would be the reason to do that, because when you use router-link links you go quickly to the already catched route

Comment: By [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) I mean using `router.push` which still navigates using vue-router but in your script code instead of in the template.  Don't replace `<router-link>` with `<a>` but instead just replace with plain text (styled if you want to look like a link).  When clicked it should activate a method.  By executing the navigation in a method you can perform other side effects first like closing your menu.